# How to have a content type that displays a title, a description and a list of feeds imported from an external URL such as blogspot?

Tags: 7, feeds

I know this is already discussed, I read many answers, but I am unable to make this simple operation.

I want a content type that displays a title a description and a list of feed items from an external URL that user can set when creates this content type node.

Ok, I installed feeds module, created an importer.
Before this I created a content type named "blogger" (for test only).
So I created an importer also named "blogger" and I attached to "blogger" content type.

Then I set fetcher as http download and parser to rss.
Now, in processor settings I can see bundle that are my content type installed, so I selected blogger, but I tried to select feed item, the result is the same.
In mapping I am confused: I tried to set all possible combinations; I set item guid as unique field.
I then create a node type of blogger content type, and I added URL of my blogspot page. I named this node "test page".
When I view "test page" I can't see feed items that are imported.
Drupal creates 25 node of "blogger" type, that are my feed items, but I don't want this.

Now, I wrong something in settings of feeds module? Or feeds module is not my way?

I only want see my blogspot items all in my test page; that's it...

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Drupal creates 25 node of "blogger" type, that are my feed items, but I don't want this.

There is a difference between attaching an importer to a content type and selecting a content type on the node processor. The first one is meant as a sort of "container" - you'll need to create nodes of this type in order to import content. The content type select on the node processor is the type of nodes that Feeds will create when you import content. Make sure that these two settings are always different.

So you need to make sure that you have two content types:

- One content type - called "blogger" for example - is the content type that you attach the importer to. This setting can be found under "Basic settings". This means you need to create a node of this type in order to import content.
- The second content type - called "blog item" for example - is the type of content that you want Feeds to create. Select this content type on the node processor.

When you now create a "blogger" node and provide a source - in your case an URL since you selected the HTTP fetcher for your importer - Feeds will create nodes of type "blog item".

In order to show the blog items on your blogger node, you'll need to create a View and find a way to display that View on your blogger node. One way of doing that would be using a block that is only shown on your blogger content type.

If you want to have a head start with this, I recommend to install the Feeds News module (this module is included with Feeds). This demonstrates how to use the attach to content type feature. It also includes a View for displaying the imported items (though on a separate page).